# Can I have an onload script on the create entity workflow step form?

Tags: javascript, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, onload, crm

I know on the regular create/edit entity it's trivial. What I'm looking at is when creating an entity via workflow, you can click on 'Set Properties' which opens a form that's different than the standard form. Is it possible to have a custom onload event in there?

One example of something we do is that we convert a text box into a drop down menu dynamically based on information in their CRM system. This breaks in the workflow form.

If you need me to clarify anything, please ask. I've included screen shots of what I'm talking about with the workflow form.

[image: Workflow]

[image: This for is where I want the onload to fire.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the form you see in the workflow designer is the current default form for that entity - it also has all the hidden/unused fields tagged onto the bottom.

All form JavaScript is disabled I believe. Perhaps look at another approach?

Comment: James, thanks for the reply.

Can anyone else confirm that you can't have an onload event here?

Answer (score 2):

You're cross pollinating your concepts.

The Workflow form is something your end user will never see.  As such, the screen you get is form that contains all fields for your entity.

The Dialog screen is the one you use when you require a user to interact with a controlled process.  However, this too is not able to have the customizations you mention.

The concept of Webresources only affects Forms; and this is where your GUI-magic impresses your customer with your ability to help him (or her) better use your design.

(If this is unclear, the answer is "no", you cannot use your webresources and custom controls on workflows.)

Comment: Our customers are fully capable of creating their own workflows on our entities and we support this so it is very likely and very common that our customer will see this form.

Comment: I was unclear, when the form is running, it will never be seen.  When it is being designed, it will be seen.